# CustomCell Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, tableview, unrecognized-selector

I am using CustomCell tableview, download data and binding it.When i tap multiple time am getting this error.

```
[NSCFString numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bd170
Sat Jan 22 12:03:26 unknown Fridge[535] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bd170'
 *** Call stack at first throw:
 (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x314d0987 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x319a149d objc_exception_throw + 24
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x314d2133 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x31479aa9 ___forwarding___ + 508
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x31479860 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
  5   UIKit                               0x339023fb -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _updateNumSections] + 66
  6   UIKit                               0x3390235b -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 50
  7   UIKit                               0x33902111 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] + 64
  8   UIKit                               0x33902069 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 64
  9   UIKit                               0x33901bff -[UITableView reloadData] + 582
  10  UIKit                               0x33904a0b -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 50
  11  UIKit                               0x33904e63 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 18
  12  UIKit                               0x338b10cf -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 26
  13  CoreFoundation                      0x3146ebbf -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 22
  14  QuartzCore                          0x30a6c685 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 120
  15  QuartzCore                          0x30a6c43d CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 184
  16  QuartzCore                          0x30a6656d _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 212
  17  QuartzCore                          0x30a66383 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 190
  18  QuartzCore                          0x30a89f9d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 52
  19  CoreFoundation                      0x31460c59 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
  20  CoreFoundation                      0x31460acd __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
  21  CoreFoundation                      0x314580cb __CFRunLoopRun + 854
  22  CoreFoundation                      0x31457c87 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
  23  CoreFoundation                      0x31457b8f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
  24  GraphicsServices                    0x35d664ab GSEventRunModal + 114
  25  GraphicsServices                    0x35d66557 GSEventRun + 62
  26  UIKit                               0x338d5329 -[UIApplication _run] + 412
  27  UIKit                               0x338d2e93 UIApplicationMain + 670
  28  Fridge                              0x00002a7f main + 70
  29  Fridge                              0x00002a34 start + 40
 )
Sat Jan 22 12:03:26 unknown UIKitApplication:com.sdi.Fridge[0xa6da][535] <Notice>: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'






**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x184250'**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the detail view of your problem but the only important part is this

```
-[NSCFString numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector
```

It tells that you are calling the method `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` on a `NSCFString`

which is seem to be wrong

so check where is that method called in your code

And also the rest is not require in your case.

Edit:

did you release your custom cell in the delegate method tableview. if yes than use autorelease instead.

Comment: this is how we trace the error in our project, so keep that in mind henceforth.

Comment: Thanks robin, This problem is not occurred when i used smoothly, I touch it multiple time continuously on tablview. Sometime it throws -[NSCFString numberOfSectionsInTableView:] or  -[CALayer numberOfSectionsInTableView:]:

Comment: it means that you are releasing some objects like custom cell. when ever same this thing happens (-[NSCFString numberOfSectionsInTableView:]) it means that the object on which methods are called are now pointing to other types of object. and which mostly happens when you release these objects. it use to happen to me all the time. what i did, i never released any object in the first run. and after the project is working fine then i release object and checked what is the behavior of the program. try it your self.

Comment: if you can post some parts of your code here may be others can also help too and new programmers will not repeat the same thing in there code